# How to express the idea of the company I am working for and not my company?

Tags: word-choice

Ok, English is my second language, and sometimes I have the following confusing situation.

When on the train, I told a friend of mine that “My company is not doing well these days. By *my company* I mean the company that I am working for, not the company that I own. Native speakers often think I own a company.

If I say “the company that I am working for is not doing well these days”, then it will be too long.

How can I express the idea that I am not the owner of the company I am working for?

Comment: ...Our company?

Comment: just that simple?

Comment: Context is important. 'The company that I am working for is not doing well these days' distances you from the company (which you may want to do).

Comment: How about 'my employers'?

Comment: I often refer to my employer as "my company" though it would be ambiguous without context.  In the absence of such context, you can provide it by using the "too long" version, which isn't that long after all, or by saying "my employer isn't...."

Comment: If it was someone who knew me well enough to know the name of the company, I think I would use its name - '*Super Lollipops* are having a tough year due to the poor summer weather'. But if I was just speaking to someone who didn't know much about me, I think I would say *The company I'm with are in trouble*.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Our company was my first thought, too.

Comment: The company you're working for *is* your company. Few people would assume you own the company if  you call it yours.

Comment: If you work for the company then "my company" is perfectly correct in the US.  You can also say "my employer" or "the company I work for".  If you're a contractor vs a "regular" employee then it might be "the company I work for" or "the company I represent".

Comment: What @Robusto said. But if you *do* find yourself in contexts where you're concerned people might get the wrong impression, just say *My **employer's business** isn't doing so well*. Note that it wouldn't necessarily work to say *My **employer** isn't doing so well*, since people might assume your boss's personal health is deteriorating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the US, if you say, "My company is not doing well these days," most folks will assume that you are referring to the company you work for.

If you say, "My *business* is not doing well these days," they'll assume that you're the boss.